# Blazor problem connecting the UI with the code

Tags: asp.net-core, user-interface, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm using Blazor Server application in Visual Studio 2019. In the .razor page I have:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">
            <label for="ConnectionStringEdit" id="Label1">Connection String for destination</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input type="text" id="ConnectionStringEdit" name="ConnectionStringEdit" text=@ConnectDestination spellcheck="false" style="width: 585px; height: 26px;" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-auto">
            <input type="submit" id="btnConnect" name="btnConnect" value="Connect" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Connect1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

now in the code part I have

```
@code {


    private string ConnectDestination { get; set; } = "";
    
    private void Connect1()
    {
        if (ConnectDestination.Length > 0)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

When I insert something in the Input and I press the button, ConnectDestination doesn't take the value of the Input Control. So this last If condition is never true. How do I get the inserted value of the Input control named ConnectionStringEdit?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `@bind-value="@ConnectDestination"`

you could also use the short directive `@bind` instead:

`@bind="@ConnectDestination"`

Note: All the input element's types are bound through the `value` attribute of the element.

Note: Both `@bind-value` and `@bind` are compiler directive instructing the compiler to emit code, behind the scene, that enables two way data-binding between a variable and an Html tag. The compiler  create a two-way data binding by binding a variable to the `value` attribute of the element, something equivalent to this:

`value="@ConnectDestination"`, which creates a one direction binding from the variable to the bound element. The compiler also creates an event call back which enables binding from the element to the variable, something equivalent to this:

`@onchange="@((args) => ConnectDestination = args.Value?.ToString())"`

This means that you could do that yourself, if you wish to have more control over the binding. You'll usually do something like this:

```
value="@ConnectDestination" @onchange="OnChange"
```

And define the call back method like this:

```
private void OnChange(ChangeEventArgs args) 
{
   // Note that it is your responsibility to update the 
   // ConnectDestination  variable:

      ConnectDestination = args.Value?.ToString());
}
```

Note: This is wrong:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnConnect" name="btnConnect" value="Connect" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Connect1">
```

The type attribute of the input element should be set to `button`:

```
<input type="button"
```

Blazor App is an SPA... meaning no submit. The only place you use the "submit" button is when you use the EditForm component, and even then the "submit" action is intercepted and canceled by the Blazor.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
<input type="text" id="ConnectionStringEdit" name="ConnectionStringEdit" @bind=@ConnectDestination spellcheck="false" style="width: 585px; height: 26px;" class="form-control">
```

or

```
<input type="text" id="ConnectionStringEdit" name="ConnectionStringEdit" value="@ConnectDestination"
           @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs __e) => ConnectDestination = __e?.Value?.ToString())" spellcheck="false" style="width: 585px; height: 26px;" class="form-control">
```